# How do I enable Google App Engine API with Terraform?

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-platform

I'm attempting to enable the AppEngine service via Terraform but I'm getting an error:

```
Error: Error creating App Engine application: googleapi: Error 403: App Engine Admin API has not been used in project <redacted> before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/appengine.googleapis.com/overview?project=<redacted> then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry., accessNotConfigured
```

As far as I know all that should be required to enable the service/API is:

```
// Enable AppEngine API - required to automagically create datastore
resource "google_project_service" "appengine_api" {
  project = var.project
  service = "appengine.googleapis.com"

  disable_dependent_services = true
}
```

Comment: "If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry., accessNotConfigured" What does it do if you retry a bit later ? (a null_resource just to wait a few minutes before the rest of your plan could be a solution if it works after a retry)

Comment: @Tensibai, not a timing issue in this case. The API was enabled successfully but all following attempts to create the appengine app fail with that error.

Comment: Yes that's what the message says, the API is created but you may need to way a bit to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The terraform service account was located in a separate project and the API needed to be enabled for appengine in the account the Terraform service account runs in even though it was creating a resource in an another project.